# Authentication Between Web API, Web App and Mobile App

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have three application Web API, MVC Application(Web App), Java Native App(Mobile App). I need to authenticate my web app and mobile app from web api. So which authentication is best for this scenario?

Please help me, I have experience of developing on MVC Application but with Web API it is new for me and for same android which is also new to me?

Comment: Take a look at Auth0: https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/mobile-api

Comment: Should i use cookie based authentication or Token based Authentication or any other...

Comment: Go through the documentation of Auth0. They outline most architecture scenarios and the best practices for authentication for those scenarios.

Comment: Is this free or paid?

Comment: I would also second what @NolanBradshaw says. go with Auth0. If you are a beginner, dont go with IdentityServer4. Its not exactly beginner friendly. its free for beginners and i have a repository here showing an API with Auth0 implemented. https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/APIServerDotNetCoreWithAuth0

Comment: My Web App is on .Net instead of .net Core

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/

It will provide you with different authentication and authorization options. You might opt to use social identity server like Google or Facebook, or go with your own identity provider. In both cases the protocols you need to know about are:

1. Check out what openid connect is: https://openid.net/connect/

> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.

2. Check out what oauth 2.0 is: https://oauth.net/2/

> OAuth 2.0 is the industry-standard protocol for authorization. OAuth 2.0 focuses on client developer simplicity while providing specific authorization flows for web applications, desktop applications, mobile phones, and living room devices.

For web app SPA use the implicit grant

For native apps, great read here: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/oauth-native-apps/

> The current industry best practice is to use the Authorization Flow while omitting the client secret, and to use an external user agent to complete the flow.

Last but not least, if you want to create your own identity provider you can use the open source identity server for both openid connect and oauth2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/cloud-native/identity-server

Comment: Just want to add my own thoughts here to this. I spent a considerable amount of with the above, exact set of links, when I was beginning to work with OAuth and what the OP was asking about. If a developer is already familiar with OAuth2 then, it makes a lot of sense to go with IdentityServer4. But, unfortunately, I have found the IdentityServer4 lacking in documentation that is beginner friendly, and its a herculean task (for a beginning) to even get something as simple as Google Sign in to work, deploy it on their own server, get the CORS setup and what not.

Comment: Fair comment, it's not very easy to handle, yet it's the right way to go

Comment: For beginners, I would strongly suggest a ready to use OAuth facility such as Auth0 or Okta or even something from the social media folks like Google or Facebook or Firebase.

Comment: Its definitely the right way to go, once enough experience has been gathered.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest for you to use web tokens and to implement it in your Web API project, i encourage you to see these series of videos to do that, It's describe how to implement JWT in Asp.net Core Web API project:

1. [ASP.NET Core Authentication with JWT  (JSON Web Token)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWkPdurauaA)
2. [ASP.NET Core Authentication with Custom Handler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Go46VRs7hI)
3. [Role-based Authorization in ASP.Net Core (With Custom Authentication Handler)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-N6O2rtCdI8)
4. [Policy-based Authorization in ASP.Net Core (with Custom Authorization Handler)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMx_jrFpEkc)
5. [JWT Refresh Token in ASP.Net Core (a deep dive)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7JP7V59X1sk)

That series will help you to build JWT in your Web API, And if you want to implement OAuth 2.0 and OpenID you can read the guideline for the protocol and you'll implement by your own, It's not default to implement.

[EDIT]
you can use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect) for OpenID after seeing that series, and this Article will be helpful [.NET Core 2.x native OpenID Connect example](https://docs.openathens.net/display/public/OAAccess/.NET+Core+2.x+native+OpenID+Connect+example)

Comment: On of my friend suggest me that :-

1. If you have to support only web application go for Cookie or Token based authentication.

2. For Single SignOn OpenId has taken most of the consumer market, SAML is often the choice for many enterprise application.

3. If you have to support both web as well mobile client go with API-token with that of Cookie based authentication.

Comment: Ok, First thing you have to migrate your application from .Net Framework to .Net Core, The other thing about your friend he's right now but SAML as a little  bit old and OIDC wright now is the best and it's the standard for web authorization.